# Trying to get all values in a dict

Tags: python, json, pokeapi

I'm getting data from [PokeAPI](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/25) but if the atribute has more than one value like `abilities` and `stats` I get only the last one.

```
dic_abi = {} #logic for abilities
for i in lista['abilities']:
    dic_abi = i['ability']['name']

contexto = {
    #"pokemons": dic,
    'ID': lista['id'],
    'Nome': lista['name'],
    'Tipo': lista['types'],
    'Peso': lista['weight'],
    'Altura': lista['height'],
    'Habilidades': dic_abi, #more than one value
    'Estatisticas': lista['stats'] #more than one value
}
```

JSON that I'm trying to get:

```
{"abilities":[{"ability":{"name":"static","url":"https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/9/"},"is_hidden":false,"slot":1},{"ability":{"name":"lightning-rod" ........
```

Comment: I guess you want to do this `dic_abi['name'] = i['ability']['name']`, but be more specific what you want `dic_abi` to be(give an example).

Comment: if i do this a must create a list to put the names on it as values to the key 'name', but it didn't work as well...

Comment: dic_abi = {'name': [name1, name2,...]} for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve. If you want to make a list of abilities' names in `lista['abilities']`, then you could do list comprehension instead of a for loop

```py
dic_abi = [i['ability']['name'] for i in lista['abilities']]
```

If instead you want to create a dict with abilities' names as `key` and the abilities as `value` (**probably that's what you want**), then you should to this:

```py
for i in lista['abilities']:
    dic_abi[i['ability']['name']] = i['ability']
```

or with dict comprehension:

```py
dic_abi = {i['ability']['name']: i['ability'] for i in lista['abilities']}
```

Comment: Basically, what you were doing, was instead of creating a dict with dictionaries of the abilities, you were overwriting the dictionary with the dictionary of the ability with every iteration of the loop. So only the dictionary at the last iteration was 'saved'

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I'm trying to do something like this: dic_abi = {'name': [name1, name2,...]} for example. And I think the second code you send will be usefull